# Pjsip android .so file Generation for different arch like x86,armeabi,arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

Tags: pjsip

I have one question regarding the .so file generation in pjsip for andorid.I am trying to generate .so file for different archs like x86,armeabi,arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a etc.

I am following the bellow link
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

I am always ended up generating the .so only for armeabi arch only, eventhough i mentioned TARGET_ABI=x86  that is stated in the above link.

These are executed commands i used to generate for .so file x86 arch.

export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/hari/AndroidSDK/ndk-bundle

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 TARGET_ABI=x86 ./configure-android --use-   ndk-cflags

make dep && make clean && make

Then moved to swig to run "make" command.

Can you please suggest me how to solve this .

Thanks for the anwers.

Comment: Can you finish compile for x86?
I got a error message "asm-generic/posix_types.h: No such file or directory" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing good. You have to manually change the name of the folder to the arch that you compile. Check this text of the Getting Started guide:

Run make from directory $PJDIR/pjsip-apps/src/swig (note that the Android NDK root should be in the PATH), e.g:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
$ cd pjsip-apps/src/swig
$ make
```

This step should produce:

- native library libpjsua2.so in pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi

  - **note**: if you are building for other target ABI, you'll need to manually move libpjsua2.so to the appropriate target ABI directory, e.g: jniLibs/armeabi-v7a, please check ​[here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#am) for target ABI directory names.

So, if you want the .so files for x86, armeabi, arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a, you have to compile PJSIP 4 times with the desired arch, and each time, change the name of the generated armeabi folder for the name of the arch you want. Example: for armeabi-v7a, change the armeabi folder name to "armeabi-v7a".

Hope this can help you.